# browser detection for iPhone 4

Tags: asp.net, html, iphone-4, browser-detection

Is there a reliable way to detect iPhone 4 (as opposed to iPhone 3 or iPad)? extra points if you can do it with .browser files or WURFL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checkout [51degress.mobi](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC) on codeplex. It is active and I have had good experience with it in past.

There is another codeplex project too but its no longer active: [Mobile Device Browser File](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/)

To detect iPhone 4 specifically, use:

```
string strUserAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToString().ToLower();
if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice == true && strUserAgent.Contains("iphone OS 4")) 
{
    // code for iPhone 4
}
```

iPhone user agents look like (`n` stands for version like 4_3_3)

> Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS
>   4_n_n like Mac OS X; en-us)
>   AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293
>   Safari/6531.22.7

Comment: like i mentioned in my question, i'd love to be able to use either of those, but as far as I can tell you can only identify iPhones in general, not iPhone 4 specifically.

Comment: yeah but won't `strUserAgent.Contains("iphone OS 4")` match any device running iOS 4.x, regardless of whether or not it is an iPhone 4 device. iow, can't an iPhone 3GS run iOS 4

Comment: Yes but why do you care? The browser and its features will be same.

Comment: screen resolution is not. i want to adjust my viewport width if it's iphone4

Comment: Couple of ways: use a media query: `<link media=”all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2)” href=”iphone4.css” type=”text/css” rel=”stylesheet” />`; meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> ` or in JS detect `screen.height/width` (will be 320/480 for iPhone 4)

Comment: hmmm, i was hoping for something that would translate to a server-side solution, but i guess long term this is the better way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified *why* you want to do browser detection, but the standard reason is because certain browsers or versions don't support a given feature that you want to use.

If that's the case, have you considered feature detection instead? A tool like [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) should be able to help with that.

[EDIT] If all you want to do is measure the screen resolution, you can  use `screen.width` and `screen.height` in Javascript.

Hope that helps.

Comment: to take advantage of the increased resolution on iphone4, i want to adjust my viewport meta tag if it's an iphone4 device. any idea if modernizr can help with that?

Comment: I don't think Modernizr will do that, but you can get the screen resolution easily enough in Javascript with `screen.width` and `screen.height`.